# Error: object of type 'NoneType' has no len() while implemeting Merge Sort recursively

Tags: recursion, python-3.7, mergesort

I'm trying to implement merge sort using python 3.7. For that I've written a merge() function and a recursive sort() function. Here sort() function breaks a list until it has one element. But the problem is the interpreter cannot recognize the arguments m and n of the merge function as lists and hence showing the following error:

```
def merge(m, n):
    x = y = 0
    v = []
    while x < len(m) and y < len(n):
        if m[x] < n[y]:
            v.append(m[x])
            x = x + 1
        elif m[x] > n[y]:
            v.append(n[y])
            y = y + 1
        else:
            v.append(m[x])
            x, y = x + 1, y + 1
    while x < len(m):
        v.append(m[x])
        x = x + 1
    while y < len(n):
        v.append(n[y])
        y = y + 1
    return v

def sort(a):
    if len(a) == 1:
        return a
    else:
        merge(sort(a[:len(a) // 2]), sort(a[len(a) // 2:]))

x = list(range(10, 0, -1))
sort(x)
print(x)
```

Expected result id the sorted list.

But python is showing this error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "", line 1, in 
        sort(x)
      File "", line 5, in sort
        merge(sort(a[:len(a) // 2]), sort(a[len(a) // 2:]))
      File "", line 5, in sort
        merge(sort(a[:len(a) // 2]), sort(a[len(a) // 2:]))
      File "", line 5, in sort
        merge(sort(a[:len(a) // 2]), sort(a[len(a) // 2:]))
      File "", line 4, in merge
        while x < len(m) and y < len(n):
    TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The point is that your sort function does return a if len(a) == 1 but does not return anything if len(a) != 1. It should be return merge(…) instead of just merge(…) in the else part of your sort.

Comment: Thank you so much for pointing out the stupid mistake I committed. I'm really grateful to you.

Comment: There is also an issue when m[x] == n[y], as only m[x] is appended, but both x and y are incremented.

Answer (score 0):

Fixes noted in comments. As an alternative, a one time allocation of a working array could be done and the merge sort would just use indexing as opposed to making multiple copies of the array.

```
def merge(m, n):
    x = y = 0
    v = []
    while x < len(m) and y < len(n):
        if m[x] <= n[y]:                # fix
            v.append(m[x])
            x = x + 1
        else:
            v.append(n[y])
            y = y + 1
    while x < len(m):
        v.append(m[x])
        x = x + 1
    while y < len(n):
        v.append(n[y])
        y = y + 1
    return(v)

def sort(a):
    if len(a) == 1:
        return(a)
    else:
        return(merge(sort(a[:(len(a)//2)]), sort(a[len(a)//2:])))

# test sort
x = list(range(10, 0, -1))
x = sort(x)                             # fix
print(x)
```